# How to redirect page and js using javascript on external domain based on referer?

Tags: javascript, redirect, external, referer

I have some sites `mysite1.com`, `mysite2.com`,....`mysiten.com`

All `mysite1-n.com` using external javascript on `myexternalsite.com/mainfile.js`

I want,

if (`mysite1-n.com`) visitors come from `www.google.com` then will redirect to `welcome.com`

if (`mysite1-n.com`) visitors come from `www.yahoo.com` then will redirect to `welcome2.com`

if (`mysite1-n.com`) visitors come from `www.anotherdomain.com` then will call javascript on `myexternalsite.com/file1.js` and working using this script

And if (`mysite1-n.com`) visitors come from bookmark then will call javascript on `myexternalsite.com/file2.js` and working using this script

What sort of script should I be using on `myexternalsite.com/mainfile.js` ?

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

basically you should check for document.referrer value and the document.location.href to do achieve what you want. This with a bunch of regexp should do the trick easily.

ex:

```
if( document.location.href.match(/^https?:\/\/mysite1-n.com/) ){
  if( document.referrer.match(/google.com/) ){
    window.location = 'http://welcome.com';
  }
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = 'myexternalsite.com/mainfile.js';
  document.head.appendChild(s);
}
```

and so on

Comment: thank's, but I'm very stupid in javascript... Can you make for me the script ?